# R - Subset dataframe where 2 columns have values

Tags: r, subset

How can I subset a dataframe where 2 columns have values?

For example:

```
A B
1 2
3 
5 6
  8
```

becomes

```
A B
1 2
5 6
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you are calling "missing". The value `NA` is different from `""`.

Answer (score 2):

One easiest way is to use `na.omit` **(if you are targeting NA values)**.
Kindly go through following R code snippet:

```
> x
   a  b
1  1  2
2  3 NA
3  5  6
4 NA  8
> na.omit(x)
   a b
 1 1 2
 3 5 6
```

Another way is to use `complete.cases` as shown below:

```
> x[complete.cases(x),]
    a b
  1 1 2
  3 5 6
```

You can also use `na.exclude` as shown below:

```
> na.exclude(x)
    a b
  1 1 2
  3 5 6
```

Hope it works for you!

Comment: @Provisional.Modulation- Hope above solutions are pointers for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
> subset(df, !is.na(df$A) & !is.na(df$B))
> df[!is.na(df$A) & !is.na(df$B),]
> df[!is.na(rowSums(df)),]
> na.omit(df)
```

all equivalent